# Нет поключения с БД. Что делать?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP скрипт выдает ошибку **Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**. Хотя подключение должно происходить совсем от другого пользователя с паролем. Как исправить эту ошибку?

**UPD**: Я еще в Терминал вводил такую комманду - ***sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/***. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: смотреть создан ли пользователь, к которому пытаетесь подключиться. И посмотрите, правильно ли в коде все прописано

Comment: Да, скорее всего ошибка именно в коде. Может где-то в подключённом файле дублируется соединение..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот полноценный пример использования БД, проверьте что есть все ключевые моменты в вашем коде, такие как задание пароля и выбор базы.

```
<?php
// Соединяемся, выбираем базу данных
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Соединение успешно установлено';
mysql_select_db('my_database') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

// Выполняем SQL-запрос
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

// Выводим результаты в html
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Освобождаем память от результата
mysql_free_result($result);

// Закрываем соединение
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: забудьте о mysql. Испльзуйте либо mysqli либо PDO